# why not work limit on query yii2

Tags: php, yii2

why not work limit on query below

When I delete Limit, the query works fine

But when Limit is put down, only a record is displayed

```
$query = Vendor::find()
            ->joinWith("city")
            ->joinWith("category")
            ->where(['{{%vendor}}.status' => 2, 'category' => 4])
            ->andFilterWhere(['=', '{{%vendor}}.city', 233])
            ->orderBy(['{{%vendor}}.id' => SORT_DESC])->limit(3)->all();
```

Thanks for the advice

Comment: Without using limit how many records you get?

Comment: 5 record displayed

Comment: It is not,The yii2 documentation is used simultaneously by Limit and all ()

Comment: sorry my bad, you are right, we can use all and limit simultaneously. how many records are you getting?